# problem installing ruby-debug-ide gem with jruby 1.4.0

Tags: jruby

I tried to follow the UsingTheJRubyDebugger instructions on the jruby wiki.  (kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/UsingTheJRubyDebugger).  I got an error trying to install the ruby-debug-ide gem.

jruby -S gem install --ignore-dependencies ruby-debug-ide
JRuby limited openssl loaded. gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
http://jruby.kenai.com/pages/JRuby_Builtin_OpenSSL
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task '2>&1'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

I'm using Vista. Has anybody gotten this to work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

hhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRuby does not support native extensions. A related stackoverflow question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526205/jruby-windows-and-native-extensions-how-do-i-distinguish-them).

Second try:

There is [bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4213) and a workaroud: `set rake=jruby -S rake`.

Comment: I am aware of that and the UsingTheJRubyDebugger wiki page has a workaround for that.  

A post in the jruby mailing list said to use the following, but I get the same result.

jruby -J-Djruby.launch.inproc=false -S gem install --ignore-dependencies ruby-debug-ide 

JRuby tries to run Ruby code in the same JVM to avoid the startup hit,
but the shell I/O redirection confuses it.

Comment: Sorry, now you have a perfectly useless answer. :-) I don't know if vista supports redirecting stderr to stdout this way. It did not complain.